# What is the idiomatic way to add space after a div table?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have space after the table. I know that `<br>` works, but I want to find out if there is a CSS attribute I can add that will make it unnecessary.

```css
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.body-settings {
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.site-wrapper {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.rTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.rTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.rTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.rTableCellBold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body class="body-settings">
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="rTable">
        <div class="rTableRow">
            <div class="rTableCellBold">Subject Name:</div>
            <div class="rTableCell"> John Doe</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow">
            <div class="rTableCellBold">Occupation:</div>
            <div class="rTableCell"> Professional Impersonator</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bold">
        Executive Summary
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that I did not add `rTableCellBold` to the `display: table-cell;` list:

```css
.rTableCell, rTableCellBold {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

After this change, I was able to use

```css
.rTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `margin-bottom` on `rTable`.

```css
.body-settings {
    font-family: opensans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.site-wrapper {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.rTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.rTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.rTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<body class="body-settings">
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="rTable">
        <div class="rTableRow">
            <div class="rTableCellBold">Subject Name:</div>
            <div class="rTableCell"> John Doe</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow">
            <div class="rTableCellBold">Occupation:</div>
            <div class="rTableCell"> Professional Impersonator</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bold">
        Executive Summary
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the real problem. I had malformed CSS.